# Switch between cards CSS+jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, position

I made a page with cards one, under next one. I have problem with adding class to active card, Look:

```
<div id="card" class="card"></div>
<div id="card2" class="card"></div>
<div id="card3" class="card"></div>
<div id="card4" class="card"></div>

// css:
.active{z-index:999}


// JS:
$('a').on('click tap', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$('.card').removeClass('active');
$($(this).attr('href')).addClass('active');
});
```

When button is clicked jQuery firstly removes from all .card class "active" and after add .active to select element. Problem is with removing class from all divs.
I have animation between switching card.
This make situation when eg. I am on card 3 and clicked on card 4 first I'm see card one (because this is on top without .active) and after that see clicked card.
Someone can help me to solve that trouble?

Edit: Here a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2z2v7wz6/

Comment: it will be better to make a [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `z-index` of previous layer.

**JS:**

```
$('a').on('click tap', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.card').css('z-index', '0');
  $('.card.active').css('z-index', '3');
  $('.card').removeClass('active');
  $($(this).attr('href')).addClass('active');
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.active{
  z-index:4 !important;
  animation:foo 2s ease 1;
}
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/harishkommuri/xc8ebuf4/).

Comment: Happy, that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( ".card" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass( "active" );
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or plunker file with the whole code? Thanks!